# how to add further UI elements ,while maximum portion of the layout is out of the Interface builder in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am building the Ui having vertical length is very maximum.I have added buttons to the portion where the Layout was visible and I can drag and drop the Buttons.
But now how to add further Buttons to the layout?remeber Buttons should be added to a specific place like in candy crush(level selection activity).
I have tried even on Tablet View screen But still some of the portion is not visible to add button.

please help.

Comment: You can add view directly in XML.

Comment: i have to add to  specific place like in candy crush LEVEL selection Activity

Comment: Make visibility of some items GONE then add your buttons & again make GONE to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using adt so,for it follow the following..

windows->android virtual devices->click on device definition tab->creat new device or make clone of the exiting one device.
through this you can make device Screen of any resolution,in which you can easily drag and drop UI elements.